# Laravel SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, connection

I can't connect to my own local database on Macos through laravel's build in database. I have tried to set the DB Socket as I can see that some faced issues, but with no luck. My .env looks like this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravelapp
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=mysql
DB_SOCKET=/Applications/AMPPS/var/mysql.sock
```

If I try to do a manual connection in a route like this:

```
Route::get('testdb', function(){
  $db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=laravelapp;charset=utf8mb4', 'root', 'mysql');
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
  $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
  $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  print_r($results);
});
```

it all works perfectly fine (so the database is open). Somehow Laravel isn't getting the mysql. What could be wrong?

Comment: I use mysql on macos and don't have the `DB_SOCKET` configuration. My guess its probably complaining about the file path you have configured for DB_SOCKET

Comment: @adam it does not work without the db_socket too :(

Comment: which MySQL Version are you using and which Laravel version are you using? I recently ran into an issue where I upgraded to mysql 8.0, what I ended up having to do was create a new user and give database rights to the new user. I used mysql workbench to create and give the new user the proper rights.

Comment: There is a difference between your `.env` config and your manually connection as you do not use a socket in your manually config. 

Check also if your socket file exist under the given path. If not, create the file with `touch mysql.sock`.